# Pass variable-size buffer from SGX enclave to outside

Tags: c, sgx

I am trying to do a function with the following prototype:

```
void pass_buffer(void** buffer_out, size_t* buffer_out_len, const void* buffer_in, size_t buffer_in_len);
```

So the idea is to pass a buffer into the enclave, and then return a response in another buffer, which can vary in size, that size being stored in `buffer_out_len`.

I'm having trouble in defining the EDL function. So my idea was to do something like:

```
public void pass_buffer([out]void** buffer_out, [out]size_t* buffer_out_len, [in, size = buffer_in_len]const void* buffer_in, size_t buffer_in_len);
```

Now, that only returns a buffer filled with one's. I know I'm supposed to pass the length of the buffer with the `size` parameter, but using a pointer in `size` was not allowed:

```
public void pass_buffer([out, size = *buffer_out_len]void** buffer_out, [out]size_t* buffer_out_len, [in, size = buffer_in_len]const void* buffer_in, size_t buffer_in_len);
```

Is my last solution possible with another syntax? Or maybe by making the return value that `size_t buffer_out_len`? If so, how do I reference it from the `size` parameter in `[out]`?

Or maybe there is another way to do this kind of behaviour? Initialise a buffer of variable size and pass it to the outside? Thanks so much.

Comment: `public` is not a C keyword. Are you really doing C or just something that looks like c.

Comment: @Pablo: The OP tagged the question [tag:sgx] and already stated that those code blocks represent EDL functions. That format matches examples [here](https://github.com/digawp/hello-enclave/blob/master/Enclave/Enclave.edl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to do what you intend to. It seems the ecall function needs to know to size of the buffer with [out] attribute when the function is called. This is also why your last solution will not work, the size function or variable is computed at function call.

I see two solutions to your problem, either use a buffer with a predetermined sufficient size, or declare an ocall function with variable size parameter, and call it from the code of your ecall function to "set" your return value. Here is an (untested) example of the second solution:

In your .edl file:

```
untrusted {
  public void get_buffer([in, size = buffer_in_len] void* buffer_in, size_t buffer_in_len);
};

trusted {
  void set_buffer([in, size = buffer_len] void* buffer, size_t buffer_len);
};
```

and in your enclave:

```
void get_buffer(void* buffer_in, size_t buffer_in_len){
  [...]
  set_buffer(my_buffer, my_buffer_len);
}
```

I'm not sure this is optimal, but it's the solution I ended up using.